# Shoulda Matchers: undefined method `is_at_least' for :last_name:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, shoulda

I am trying to validate the length of first_name:

```
 it { should ensure_length_of (:first_name).is_at_least(2)}
```

But getting the error:

> Shoulda Matchers: undefined method `is_at_least' for :last_name:Symbol

I can't find much in the docs on proper syntax in this situation.

Comment: On which line did the error occurs? Please post that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces do matters! There should be no space between method and its parameters.

```
it { should ensure_length_of(:first_name).is_at_least(2)}
```

What you have is interpreted as:

```
it { should ensure_length_of( (:first_name).is_at_least(2) )}
```